# Using group by for rows that contain particular characters, as well as normally

Tags: sql-server

I have a varchar field that I would like to group on.

Except I'd like to clump all the rows containing a `'.'` character into one group

**Starting Table**, with the following 5 entries in the "Name" field:

```
Aaa Aa
Bbb Bb
Ccc.Cc
Ddd.Dd
Eee.Ee
```

**Expected grouping**:

```
Aaa Aa
Bbb Bb
HasDot
```

Maybe using something along these lines?

```
Select "Name", count(*)
from MyTable
group by "Name"
-- group normally except for the group containing '.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN Name LIKE '%.%' THEN 'HasDot' 
            ELSE Name 
        END Name,
        COUNT(*) N
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN Name LIKE '%.%' THEN 'HasDot' 
            ELSE Name 
         END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT IIF ((charindex('.',name) >0),'HasDot',name) NAME
FROM [name1]
ORDER BY NAME
```